# Designing a board for two DC motors with an ESP32

Tags: esp32

I'm going to develop a new board for my swimming pool robot based on the ESP32. It will drive two DC motors with PWM speed control. The power supply delivers +29V DC to the board. Instead of the L7805 I will use a step down module (more efficient.) The fan motor is driven by  AOD4184 MOSFET, the wheels motor is driven by the BTM7710G H-bridge IC.

This is the first time I have used this IC, so please help me with connections and the logic input (IH1 IH2 IL1 AND IL2.)  Between logic inputs and logic outputs from the ESP a 74HCT244D will be used.

The BTM uses ST output to generate errors such as overvoltage, overtemp etc. Can I  connect this pin ditectly to the ESP? This is a 5V pin and I would use the 74HCT buffer because of the ESP32 not 5V tolerant. Can I use the buffer as input also? Do you think it will work? Do you have any tips for the project?

[image]

Comment: As you said, BTM7710G is just a H-bridge device and not at all a motor driver device, though there is such an example schematic in the datasheet. It is is an old, 2008 product and there are now many new motor drivers around. I have been playing with a couple of motor drivers, with or without PWM speed control. My feeling is that it is a bit risky to try this non DC motor driver specific device, particularly if you don't have any prior experience in specific motor driver devices, unless you have a loose schedule or deadline, and you prefer to learn by making mistakes. Good luck and cheers.

Comment: thx for answer. why did u say it s not a motor dc specific driver? it should be a motr dc driver.. it is also used in the original robot pcb aswell

Comment: I mean the device is a general H-bridge and of course you can config it to become a DC Motor driver. But it would save time if there are already DC motor drivers available, readily wired. But if you already a workable schematic, then of course you can use it directly. Perhaps you can let us have the link of the BTM7710G related tutorial you are following.

Comment: @tlfong01: what's the difference between a DC motor driver and a general H-bridge?

Comment: (1) Well, a motor driver is basically a full H-bridge, with control and status stuff. (2) A full bridge is basically two half bridges. (3) A half-bridge is basically two transistor switches. So actually you can DIY a motor driver bottom up, all from transistors, or from  the middle, with half or full H-bridges. (4) I am a lazy guy, I don't want to learn or DIY anything, so I just use a fully assembled motor driver, never mind bridge or not  Happy learning. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

> The BTM uses ST output to generate errors such as overvoltage,
> overtemp etc... Can I connect directly this pin to the ESP?

The ST pin is "open drain". You may pull the pin up to ESP32 rail voltage (3.3V?), .. use a 10k ohm. If ESP32 input can be configured with internal pull-up, the external pull-up "may" not needed.

> This is a 5V pin and I would use the 74HCT buffer because of the ESP32
> not 5V tolerant. Can I use the buffer as input also? Do you think it
> will work? Do you have any tips for the project?

If you'd prefer to pull-up the ST pin to 5V and using a buffer, 74LVC series can take 5V input while operating at 3.3V. 74HCT series are TTL compatible and requires 5V for operation.

---

**ST pin is Open Drain:**
[image]

**ST pin can take up to 5mA:**
[image]

Comment: ok so if i connect the ST pin to 2y1 i can read the status of ST from 2a1 with the esp32?

Comment: The ST pin is output. So, the other way around: (ST + pull-up to VCC) -> 2A1, 2Y1 -> ESP32. I have not checked, but you did(?), ESP Vcc is 5V, right?

Comment: esp32 has vin +5v but there is a 3.3v volt regulator inside so the logic is 3.3v